# How to pass specificly sized array as argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

I have a function that generates a safe input with error handling so it's cleaner to input numbers (int). But I want one of the argument to be an optional array of length 2 that contains the boundaries of the wanted variable input.

Here's what I have for now :

```
//function prototype
void input_number(int* variable, string text = "Input : ", int boundaries[2] = NULL);

//function call
int variable;
input_number(&variable, "Choose a number between 0 and 10 : ", {0, 10});
```

This doesn't work, throwing the error `cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int*' for argument '3' to 'void input_number(int*, std::__cxx11::string, int*)'`

How can I pass an array of length 2 to the function?

Also, is `int[] = NULL` correct for a default array value or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message explains the problem - an array is converted to a pointer (to the first element) when passed as an argument to a function.

One solution would be to pass a `struct` type that has two members, and give that a default value.   An example would be, since `std::array` is actually a templated structure

```
void input_number(int* variable, std::string text = "Input : ", const std::array<int, 2> &bounds = {});

int variable;
input_number(&variable, "Choose a number between 0 and 10 : ", {0, 10});
```

However, any data structure that can store two values, and be constructed using an `initializer_list<int>`.   There are other examples of such types in the standard library - `std::array` is not the only one.

Personally, I'd also omit the first argument, and have it as a return value

```
int input_number(std::string text = "Input : ", const std::array<int, 2> &bounds = {});

 // to call

int variable = input_number("Choose a number between 0 and 10 : ", {0, 10});
```

This has the problem of the function not being able to report an error (other than by throwing an exception), but so does your approach.

Personally, I also wouldn't pass the boundaries as default arguments.  I'd simply do it with function overloading;

```
 int input_number(std::string input, int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
 {
     // do whatever you want
 }

 int input_number(std::string input)
 {
      return input_number(input, std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
 }
```

which forces the caller to either provide no arguments after the first (in which case, default bounds are used), or two (which specify the bounds) - passing only one additional argument would be a diagnosable error.    The only difference from what you've asked is that this does not require (implicitly or explicitly) constructing an array or other data structure to call the function - which is arguably easier for the caller to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Lots of extra suggestions, I love it. And yes, even if I wanted to avoid function overloading, I guess I definitely have no choices other that using them!

Comment: Just read, with the way you just wrote that overload isn't taking more space than without overloading.. very nice solution thanks! (+ there's an extra closed parenthesis in last code block, just after input, that might be removed)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void input_number(int* variable, string text = "Input : ", std::array<int, 2> boundaries = {});
```

Comment: It might also be a good suggestion to take the array as const&, but that's preference at that point: just opens up a few more use cases.

Comment: Gain nothing in this case @TheKitchenSink. Based on the error message, Asker looks to be using `{}` in the call.

Comment: Unfortunately {} doesn't mean "no array", it means "an array filled with 0s".

Comment: I worded that poorly. I should have written `{0, 10}`.

Comment: @user4581301 one can use {0,10} in this case, no problem. The problem is that it needs to be optional.

Comment: @user4581301 like I said, it opens up more use cases. It doesn't help in this case, but if you use std::array<int, 2> later on in your code, this will prevent the copy if you pass it directly. That's why I didn't open up my own answer: this works just fine for this use case.

Comment: @TheKitchenSink: Preventing a copy of a 2 integer array is not useful.  On most systems, a reference has the same size as two ints, and this function doesn't exceed the amd64 register limit for function calls.  So there'd be no benefit to using a reference in this case.

Comment: Ok, so using this method works in the way that it doesn't throw any errors and works well with default arguments. 

But, is there a way to do it so that if anyone wants to use the function later, the compiler throws an error if the passed array is of size less than 2? Because now it just fills the blanks with 0's... which is still cool but there's no benefit in comparision of simply using 2 separate optional int...

Comment: @lolgab123: Is the function always going to be called with compile-time constant integers like `{1, 2}`, or does it also need to be usable with variables like `{a, b}`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck only compile-time integers :)

Comment: If the arguments are known at compile-time, use template parameters instead of a function argument